# Question about $L^1$ space and Uniform integrability.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, uniform-integrability

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and let $\mathscr{F}=\{f_{\alpha}:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}:\alpha\in I\}$ be an arbitrary family of measurable real functions on $\Omega$.
$\mathscr{F}$ is uniformly integrable if the following two conditions hold:
\begin{equation}
    (i) \sup_{\alpha}\int_{\Omega}|f_{\alpha}|d\mu=C<\infty \hspace{1cm}
     (ii) \lim_{\mu_{(A)}\to 0}\int_{A}|f_{\alpha}|d\mu=0
  \end{equation}
Remark: (i) follows form (ii).

I want to know the difference when $\mathscr{F}\subset L^1$ and when $\mathscr{F}$ is uniformly integrable since this two looks same to me.Please help.

what I understood is that here condition (ii) means that $\forall \epsilon>0  ,\hspace{0.5 cm} \exists \delta>0$ such that $\int_{A}|f_\alpha|d\mu<\epsilon$ whenever $f\in \mathscr{F}$ and for all $\mu(A)<\delta.$

Answer (score 3):

It might help to consider a simple example:

Let $\Omega = (-2,2)$, $\Sigma$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $(-2,2)$, and $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure restricted to $(-2,2)$.

Consider $\mathscr F = \{ k\chi_{(-1,1)} \text{ s.t. } k \in \mathbb Z^+ \}.$ Each function $f_k:= k\chi_{(-1,1)}$ is in $L^1(\Omega)$ since $$ \| f_k\|_{L^1(\Omega)} = 2k < +\infty,$$ so $\mathscr F \subset L^1(\Omega)$. However, $\mathscr F$ is not *uniformly integrable* since $\| f_k\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$ is not bounded by some constant independent of $k$.

Comment: So we can say that  for every $f\in \mathscr{F}$ is uniformly integrable if there exists a constant such that $||f_{k}||_{L^{1}(\Omega)}$ is bounded ,independent of $f$.

Comment: Yes, this is what condition (i) says

Comment: And How (ii) implies (i)?

Comment: Write $\int_A \vert f_\alpha \vert d \mu = \int_\Omega  \vert f_\alpha \vert \chi_A d \mu $ then apply dominated convergence

Comment: can you explain more ,I am still confuse about after writing this, how to apply dominated convergence theorem?